# Formatting pbox in table for neat distribution of text

Tags: tables, formatting

For the purpose of a paper I am writing I have some very big tables. I couldn't fit the numbers inside the boxes so I used pbox. The problem is that now the numbers within the box aren't distributed evenly and there is too much free space in between lines. Is there a solution to it that still uses pbox?

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SOME TEXT HERE}           & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MORE TEXT}                           & number    & number    & number \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number         \\ \hline
some title here          & value       &\pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &    \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number    \\ \hline
some title here         & value                     &  \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &  \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number     \\ \hline
some title here         & value l                     &   \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}  & \pbox{25cm}{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}
```

Below I attached an image showing the current result:

[image]

Comment: Where do you get `\pbox` from?

Comment: From this package: \usepackage{pbox}

Comment: It's helpful if you make your examples complete so people can test see the result and test answers.

Comment: Further to @DavidCarlisle's comment, I don't get such a bad result when I paste your code into a basic document. Something else must be affecting the interline spacing.

Comment: the edit still does not make your posted code runnable, compare with the fragment in my answer which you can test without having to edit.

Comment: That's a valid remark Mr. David. I'll try to incorporate all the packages I use to make it easier for others to test. This is my first post here so thanks for your indulgence.

Comment: @Ian actually, neither did I get such bad spacing in my original file, but it still didn't look too good.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `makecell` package for that: it allows for linebreaks and common formatting in certain cells, with the `\makecell` and `\thead` commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|*{5}{l|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SOME TEXT HERE} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MORE TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \hline
some title here & value &\makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \hline
some title here & value & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number & number & number \\ \hline
some title here & value l & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} & \makecell{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

`pbox` doesn't seem to help you much here, I'd just use `tabular`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\pb[1]{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
\begin{table}[htp]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{SOME TEXT HERE}           & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Big title that takes the whole page} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{MORE TEXT}                           & number    & number    & number \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number         \\ \hline
some title here          & value       &\pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &    \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number    \\ \hline
some title here         & value                     &  \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 228}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}   &  \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{ANOTHER TEXT} & number    & number    & number     \\ \hline
some title here         & value l                     &   \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}& \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}  & \pb{12341 538768 \\ 23423 22}      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{There should be proper caption.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If these `\pbox`/\pb` entries are just a large single numer you want to wrap on space that could be automatic without needing to have a command and explicit `\\ ` but I left it this way as it wasn't clear in your question the input context